# Meaning of formatting mark in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Can anyone name and explain the formatting mark that appears at the end of line 2 and start of line 3 in the image below please?

The image is a screenshot taken from Word 2010 and shows text in a document header.

Thanks in advance

[image: Word formatting mark]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just the "hard-return" mark like in line 1.
It just looks different in the font that you are using in line 2-3.

Comment: Well - duh. I'd never noticed that formatting marks took on their parent font. Thanks.

Comment: @NeilMoss I didn't either until about 5 years ago I got the same question from a user when I was doing helpdesk/support. I looked at it for a couple of minutes. Tried to type a few char's and then hit the Enter key. Then I realized what was happening.